# Why is the orientability invariant under homeomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-topology, orientation

I want to show that the orientable surface and the non-orientable surface of the same genus are not homeomorphic. I tried to prove using the fact that if the fundamental groups of two spaces are not isomorphic, then two spaces are not homeomorphic. But I can't. Why is the orientability invariant under homeomorphism?

Comment: the fundamental groups of two spaces are isomorphic, then two spaces are homeomorphic. This is not correct.

Comment: Sorry, it's mistake. I want to using if the fundamental groups of two spaces are not isomorphic, then two spaces are not homeomorphic.

Comment: It depends on your knowledge about orientability, or about the orientable and non-orientable surfaces of each genus.

How do you define orientability? Depending on that your idea for a proof would be a little different. Otherwise, if you know some facts about orientable and non-orientable surfaces, like some information about their homology (the first homology group), you can use that information. Hint: Torsion subgroups.

Comment: Also since the first homology group is the abelianization of the fundamental group, that information is definitely stored in $\pi_1$ too. It's just that it's stored in a bit of a messy way and thus it's harder to understand.

Comment: You should state what definition of orientability you want to use (there are many equivalent formulations).